# Большие объемы данных

Tags: data-structures, sql, mysql, база-данных

Необходимо предоставить пользователям доступ к записям некоторой таблицы. 
В таблице имеется 11 столбцов, каждый из которых является некоторым идентификатором записи в другой таблице. 
В день кол-во записей в данной таблице увеличивается на 30 миллионов записей.
Пользователям необходимо знать кол-во событий, подходящих под заданный ими набор фильтров.
Скорость выполнения запроса допустима в пределах 1 - 3 секунд.
Всего около 5 пользователей.

Как оптимизировать работу таблицы?
Возможно, необходимо построить правильные индексы, но это все же не спасает. 
Возможно, стоит просчитывать кол-во записей, которые попадают под каждый из всевозможных фильтров. Но тогда кол-во записей возрастет во много раз.

Возможно, есть другие варианты?

Comment: Да, говоря  " Возможно, стоит просчитывать кол-во записей, которые попадают под каждый из всевозможных фильтров" я имел ввиду полный перебор всех вариантов фильтров

Comment: При таком объеме записей, работать с "живой" базой данных это не оптимально. Я бы предложил посмотреть в сторону Redis, а также возможно имеет смысл делать обобщение данных (если это возможно) раз в какое время и тут можно посмотреть на что-то типа Hadoop или использовать свой механизм map-reduce.

Comment: По поводу Redis - это хранилище не подходит для данной задачи, так как Redis хранит рабочий набор данных в оперативной памяти. То есть кроме того, что я ограничен объемом дорогой оперативной памяти, я еще и должен бояться за падение сервера. 

По поводу Hadoop - подскажите примеры, хорошие статьи, либо другую полезную информацию.

Comment: Это что за записи такие вообще? 30 миллионов в день оО

Comment: Думаю, это неважно. К сжалению, их действительно много(кол-во может варьироваться 25-35 млн). В дальнейшем их может стать еще больше.

Есть идеи?

Comment: Лучше бы структуру таблицы выложили, так будет проще.

Comment: @fff если у вас такие нагрузки ради тех пяти пользователей, то я бы не жалел оперативки :) ну и сдублировать можно сервер :)

Comment: К сожалению ничего не могу посоветовать конкретное по Hadoop. Могу лишь пару слов сказать. Hadoop это безусловно мощный инструмент для map-reduce огромного количества информации. Я подчеркиваю огромного, потому что сила его в том, что он может бежать на кластерах обрабатывая одни и теже данные, что ускоряет просто напросто процесс. Если нет кластеров, то лучше с ним не заморачиваться и сделать свой собственный map-reduce или посмотреть другие варианты.

Comment: Сколько у Вас реально используемых комбинаций фильтров? Что-то не верю, что 2^11. А запросы к этой таблице могут быть по любому периоду?

Comment: @fff, 30 млн. в день это около 1 млрд. в год (а в терабайтах - сколько получается у Вас?). А скорость примерно 350 записей в секунду (это если равномерно круглые сутки). 

Скажите, какое время хранятся эти записи? И к какому количеству (видимо запросы все-таки делаются к записям за какое-то ограниченное время) записей Вы предполагаете делать запросы?

И еще вопрос, какими аппаратными ресурсами (в т.ч. система хранения) располагаете?

--

И еще - сразу обдумайте проблему бэкапов. Возможно здесь вообще лучше делать 2 системы (active + standby) с  синхронизацией и бэкапить standby...

Answer (score 7):

30 миллионов - это много. Даже на самых хороших индексах это будет медленно. В этих случаях используют предвычисления.

К примеру, собирал статистику каждый час в отдельную таблицу(таблицы). В этом случае можно будет очень быстро с дополнительной таблицы получить данные, а остаток за последний час выбрать с основной таблицы.

Но делать постоянные выборки - это неверно. Особенно в высоконагруженных проектах. В этих случаях берут какой нибудь MQ (message Queue, например, RabbitMQ)  и данные льются в него одним потоком. А другой сервер вычитывает и обновляет счетчики. В этом случае можно будет сделать даже realtime отображение статистики. Если счетчиков много, то серверов обработки может быть много.

Понятно, что на все фильтры заранее не наготовишь счетчиков, но если подойти грамотно, то большинство задач можно покрыть. А вот редкие специфические запросы можно уже и с базы аккуратно вытянуть (я думаю, пользователи с этим смирятся).

Comment: На данный момент  я так же склоняюсь к предвычислениям. Этот подход является наиболее очевидным. Но даже если именно этот подход является идеальным для решения данной задачи, я уверен у него есть множество реализаций.

Comment: Кстати, как лучше поступить в случае предвычислений со столбцами результирующей таблицы? То есть что для MySQL будет лучше: много столбцов или мало столбцов?

Comment: 1) Для каждого столбца исходной таблицы создать соотсветствующий столбец в результирующей таблице. Соотсветсвенно при выборке данных я должен буду в SQL запрос добавить по одному where условию на каждый столбец. И индекс будет составной по всем столбцам

Comment: 2) После полного перебора всех возможных комбинаций фильтров, объединить все значений каждой комбинации в некоторую строку(или бинари) и создать только один столбец для полученного списка конкатенаций. Соотсветсвенно здесь условие будет только одно. И индекс тоже будет только один.

Comment: >  То есть что для MySQL будет лучше: много столбцов или мало столбцов?

думаю, что меньше столбцов - более правильный вариант. Как минимум будет проще делать выборки.

Я бы оставил для таблицы предвыбоки похожую на оригинальную таблицу структуру.

Answer (score 3):

Если Вас не спасает построение правильных индексов, Вам надо менять архитектуру базы данных. Возможно, так же, имеет смысл генерировать таблицы соответствующие результату работы фильтров, и делать это или "в ночь" или "на лету", при добавлении новых записей.

Comment: Наверняка эта задача является достаточно распространенной. Может быть есть какие -то распространенные подходы к решению данной проблемы? Может быть как то мне поможет партицирование таблиц?  Возможно, стоит использовать другие движки mySQL или другие БД?

Comment: Тут зависит от Вашей цели и ресурсов. Можно сделать множество "подпорок" в виде надстроек индексирования (например сфинкс). Можно продумать грамотную архитектуру бд, согласно Ваши задачам. Объём конечных данных для пользователя какой? Другую БД? Из бесплатных попробуйте postgres SQL.